Creating a custom session with php in Wordpress website
`Im trying to create a custom section like, $_SESSION(['mySession']), and a specific page just can be open if this SESSION has value, how do I implement that in a Wordpress website?
Thank you
Ive place this code in my function.php`
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

and in a php page I created to validate the a login
if($row['userPwd']==$data['userPwd']){
    $_SESSION['UserID'] = $row['userID'];
    header("Location: DestineURL");
}

if I print $_SESSION['UserID'] is showing the ID, but how can I request this session and valide it in the destinationURL?`

Does this answer your question? Wordpress *custom* Session Value usage?
